# Web-based JavaScript Debugger

Tags: javascript, firebug, cloud9-ide

I have an idea for a project that has to do with helping people learn to program. One of the things I think would be cool would be to have a place on the site where you can edit JavaScript code in real time in your browser.

I know there are a number of web-based JavaScript editors, but I haven't been able to find out if there are any tools that let you *debug* JavaScript from your browser. I think being able to step through your code is a valuable learning experience for people who are new to programming. It seems like something along those lines should be possible, though.

I originally thought you could use something like Firebug Lite: http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite, but they don't support debugging. Is this just too hard of a problem to solve in JavaScript?

Comment: Have you seen this: http://www.codecademy.com/#!/exercise/0 Pretty cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you try [Cloud9](http://c9.io/). It is a full-featured web based IDE for Javascript, which includes a great debugger. It is free for open source projects, which I imagine would include most learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the build in Javascript console from the browser? Every modern browser has this feature.

Comment: Yeah, that's a reasonable backup plan, but the friction involved for a new programmer is a lot higher than just using something on a website.