# How to view javascript console in Cloud9

Tags: javascript, html, cloud9-ide, console.log

Right now I'm using a Chromebook that does not allow me to "inspect element" on a webpage.

I would like to be able to view the javascript console log from within Cloud9.

Cloud9 seems to be able to "preview" a webpage, but it doesn't seem to have the option to view the console log from that webpage.

I feel like I should be able to do this with the [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7368476/5049813), but it may be [impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642016/can-cloud9-debug-html-javascript#comment41920111_26642016).

A way to do this (or verification that it is impossible) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript console log is not possible in the "client" in Cloud9.

Inspecting a single element on Chromebook is possible.
If you want to highlight a single element, "right click" the element and select "Inspect element" from the menu.

Source: https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20140314102249AA5VbJJ

Answer (score 1):

Cloud9 debugger works for server side code, it doesn't allow to inspect pages in the browser.